# How to highlight text in Swagger Editor?

Tags: reactjs, swagger-editor

I am working with a React app where I have a Swagger Editor and my requirement is to highlight the particular text with different color background. Something like this screen

[image]

Please let me know if it is possible and any documentation is available for this.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you ask in the Swagger Editor project repository: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues